# Typo3 onepage Template vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: typo3

We are looking for a solution to get a Typo3 Template onepage Layout. We need the classic vertical scrolling but also a horizontal scrolling for the "subpages".

We found the Template of Maximilian Mayer, http://onepage.compuart.com/
Does anybody knows if there is a way to add a horizontal scrolling to connect subpages?
Do you know other templates/concepts how to achieve this?

Regards
Jacques

Comment: Unlike Wordpress, TYPO3 is not a CMS that relies on large pools of pre-fabricated templates. You will need knowledge of TypoScript, Fluid and HTML/CSS/JS to create your website as desired.

Comment: Hi Urs. Thank you for your reply. We are just looking around, maybe there is no need to begin from scratch. Maybe there is a simple  solution to get tt_content into a bootstrap carousel.

Comment: Have a look at the introductory package that uses http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/bootstrap_package - it has good examples for integrating bootstrap features with fluid

Answer (score 0):

The package of Benjamin Kott (Thank you Benjamin) has now a onePage feature. Works great:

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package